# Can we say that Java or C# have unified inheritance trees?

Tags: java, c#, inheritance, type-systems

Can we say that Java or C# are OO languages with a unified inheritance tree/unified type system? 
By unified inheritance tree/unified type system I mean that every class derives implicitly or explicitly from one single type? Are there any object oriented language that do not follow that concept?

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. Also see [ask]

Comment: The common term for what you call a "strictly hierarchical language" is having a unified type system.

Comment: How do value types fit into this concept?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could argue that the two languages are strictly hierarchical since they both require inheritance from a base `Object` class.  But I'm not sure what that claim would buy you.  They're object oriented languages and they use a base `Object` to facilitate some language features.  Worrying about "strictly hierarchical" doesn't help a conversation about OO languages.

> Are there any objective language that do not follow that concept?

To my knowledge, C++ doesn't rely upon a unified inheritance tree.  For that matter, languages which aren't strictly or statically typed have no need for a unified inheritance tree, this group includes SmallTalk, Perl, JavaScript, and [many others](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_programming_languages).

Then there's prototypal inheritance which is unarguably OO, but attempts to accomplish the general goals of OO in a way which makes a unified type system irrelevant, because prototypal inheritance is used for extending things rather than distinguishing them.

At the end of the day it's worth noting that type systems and language design are two interwoven topics which are very complex where solutions are extremely diverse. Given the diversity and number of languages out there, you can likely find languages that approach these varying problems in as many ways as can be imagined.

To further compound the situation, it's also worth noting that the definition of "object oriented" or "objective" is not only wishy-washy but extremely controversial as you can find in many places across the internet, for example [here](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?AlanKaysDefinitionOfObjectOriented) you can find the inventor of the term advocating it's meaning as something far different from prototypal OO or C#/Java's OO, and to this day people don't agree on it's definition.

---

Here are some links to support Java & C#'s use of a base `Object` class.

- [Oracle's Java documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html)

> Excepting Object, which has no superclass, every class has one and only one direct superclass (single inheritance). In the absence of any other explicit superclass, every class is implicitly a subclass of Object.

- [MS documentation on C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.aspx)

> Supports all classes in the .NET Framework class hierarchy and provides low-level services to derived classes. This is the ultimate base class of all classes in the .NET Framework; it is the root of the type hierarchy.

- Related SO question [about inheriting from `system.object`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8299531/1345223)
- This [answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5697373/1345223) explains why C++ doesn't have a universal base object.

Comment: @JimmyHoffa both Perl (`UNIVERSAL`) and JavaScript (`Object`) have something like a root class, although both are more flexible than “usual”. I'm not sure about Smalltalk but I would think it has a root object as well.

Comment: @amon whether or not they have some unified inherited object is not relevant, because if they didn't their type systems would still function exactly as they do, you don't ever have to utilize that fact that there is a unified type in either case, and in SmallTalk the type system is even more different in that everything is the same type when instantiated, the inheritance tree exists only for composition of behaviours but not for distinction so the instances having a shared root doesn't matter because you never cast or otherwise